# netbeans error expected an operand but found

Tags: javascript, jquery, netbeans

Beginner to java trying to implement jquery into netbeans by inputting these codes into a 
javascript file to create a main-menu page. 
Utilizing jquery v 3.1.1. They highlight my second script tag saying its an error

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">  </script>
  var main = function () {

   $('.icon-menu').click(function () {
    $('.menu').animate({
       left: "0px"
    }, 200);

    $('body').animate({
        left: "285px"
    }, 200);
   });


  $('.icon-close').click(function () {
   $('.menu').animate({
       left: "-285px"
   }, 200);
   $('body').animate({
       left: "0px"
   }, 200);
  });
  };


 $(document).ready(main);/*
```

They highlight my  as an error and give the message

Menu.js:2:8 Expected an operand but found <

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">  </script>
```

Comment: java != javascript

Comment: That, and your Javascript needs to be between `<script>` and `</script>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

you should put the javascript code inside of the xml tag ():

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">  
var main = function () {

    $('.icon-menu').click(function () {
        $('.menu').animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 200);

        $('body').animate({
            left: "285px"
        }, 200);
    });


    $('.icon-close').click(function () {
        $('.menu').animate({
            left: "-285px"
        }, 200);
        $('body').animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 200);
    });
};

$(document).ready(main);
</script>
```

Also, you have an open coment "/*" at the end of your code.